# How to extend attribute mixin in Less?

Tags: less

For example, I have this Less mixin

```
.mixin(){
  background: black;

  [data-attribute]{
    color: white;
  }
}
```

How can I get only 'color' property?
e.g:

```
.my-class{
  .mixin[data-attribute](); //don't work for me
}
```